# Video Editing/After Effects Forum To Ask For Help

Tags: video, editing, recommendation, video-editor

I was wondering if anyone could suggest a good/active forum for Adobe After Effects/Video Editing in general.

I require the forum to ask for help in editing a file/some HD video or finding someone who would be willing to do such a thing.

This is as this Q&A site would not allow me to such for such help.

Comment: http://media-motion.tv/ae-list.html

Answer (score 4):

I recommend the Creative Cow web site, specifically, http://forums.creativecow.net/adobeaftereffects. This will serve your need for getting help on AE, but this is not a site for posting to find some one to do the work for you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Video Co-Pilot](http://www.videocopilot.net/).  They have several tutorials and a forum.

Comment: The question was to recommend a *forum*, not a tutorial page. I might be mistaken, but Video Co-pilot posts great tutorials, but it's not a real forum.

Comment: Both Reading forums and tutorials is for you to know about after effects. They share the same purpose...to learn. Besides, Video Co-Pilot also recommends forums on After Effects, so better check it out.

Comment: Yes, they're both for learning purpooses. The question clearly states that the asker is looking for a place where he can pose a concrete question about a certain file. A tutorial page does not allow that. Feel free to add the recommendations of Video Co-pilot to improve your answer.

Comment: The link you have provided is for a studio, not for Video Co-Pilot.  Please correct your answer.

Comment: They have a forum that is very helpful at times

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success with the Premiere forums in terms of getting my questions answered. I don't have any personal experience on the AE side of Adobe's site, but I would assume that community is active as well. Good luck!